# When trying to access a SQL Server 2008 server in my domain, I get a "server not found or was not accessible" error

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

When setting up a system that requires a remote computer to access SQL 2008 stored on another computer in the same domain, I'm running into the following error:

```
The server was not found or was not accessible.
Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server
is configured to allow remote connections.
```

When I installed SQL Server, I was sure I set up the system just so.  How can I troubleshoot this?

Comment: Have you made sure that all firewalls etc allow incoming connections? Have you tested the connection locally to make sure it is the "remote" part of "remote connection" that fails?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the name of the SQL server instance and make sure it is what you are using to connect to it. Also, look at the SQL Server Network Configuration under Configuration Tools. I worte an article about a very similar problem (if not the same) [here](http://ricardodsanchez.com/2012/04/05/how-to-configure-sql-express-to-accept-remote-connections/):

Comment: the article link is dead and I am experiencing this same problem.  What do you advise?

Comment: If you're going to link to you're own blog, can you ensure that the links don't die?

Comment: Sorry, I updated the link with a new post that is a replica of the original post which was lost when I switched blog platforms, http://ricardodsanchez.com/2012/04/05/how-to-configure-sql-express-to-accept-remote-connections/

Answer (score 8):

I appreciate this thread is old now and already has an accepted answer, but I found a slightly different solution with regards to this issue that others may find useful. From reading [this](http://www.microsoft.com/products/ee/transform.aspx?ProdName=Microsoft+SQL+Server&EvtSrc=MSSQLServer&EvtID=2) issue description I found that there were two SQL Server services in the standard Windows Local Services control panel: MSSQLSERVER and SQLEXPRESS (see below).

[image: SQL Server Services]

I found that SQLEXPRESS was running, but MSSQLSERVER was not. So I simply started that service, and I was able to connect to SQL Server again.

Comment: This guy knows what he is talking about.  Don't waste your time reading the above article.

Answer (score 2):

A couple of things to try...

- check the Configuration settings to ensure that the TCP protocol is enabled.
- try accessing the remote server via IP instead of the server name, this has worked for me in the past (oddly).

I'm assuming its running on the default port, if it isnt then you will need to specify the port number after the server-name / ip separated by a comma:

sql-server-name,{port}

Answer (score 1):

Having had this a few times even with named pipes the first thing I always try is pre-pending the server name before the named instance; so SERVER\namedinstance. You can manually overwrite the dropdown values in the connect . So ideally in the setup it should have a brief tip below the named instance box like Enter SERVER\namedinstance. Although knowing MS if you entered this you'd probably end up with SERVER\SERVER\namedinstance...! 
You can also use the browse option (bottom of server dropdown) and if you're lucky it may be in the 2nd tab (Network Servers) - even if it's a local install.

Answer (score 0):

The program you are running needs to be running under an account which has access to the network (and depending on protocol chosen, may need access to the SQL Server by role or whatever).  This error indicates that it is not finding the server on the network by name or IP.

The most common case I have seen this is when you have a web app running under a local account which does not have network access attempting to access SQL Server on another machine.

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to the server that SQL Server is running on, you can try:

-Opening SQL Server Configuration Manager
-In the left pane, click 'SQL Server Network Configuration' and then 'Protocols for [instance name, possibly SQLEXPRESS]'
-Right click TCP/IP again and you'll see the port used.  Mine was listed under IPAll/TCP Dynamic Port.
-In SQL Server Management studio add the port name to your connection string as follows:

if you were connecting to:

```
MYSERVER\SQLEXPRESS
```

the port is specified as

```
MYSERVER,2071\SQLEXPRESS
```