# Unable to find the sql server in dropdown list of server names

Tags: sql, sql-server, entity-framework, connection, entity-model

Actually I am trying to connect to database using entity model .But during this process when I am trying to access my database I am unable to find my server in the list of dropdown during connection.Can anyone help me out ....Thanx in advance..Below is the screenshot of the same.
[image]

Comment: I'm not sure about this, but have you tried starting SQL Browser Service?

Comment: yeah I have enabled it automatically

Comment: And what about [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1507004/when-trying-to-access-a-sql-server-2008-server-in-my-domain-i-get-a-server-not)?

Answer (score 0):

If the database is on your local machine, you can just enter a dot for the server name.

Comment: And what if it's SQL Express? It's usually under a named instance.